# Angular2-meteor socially demo No Directive annotation found

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I am doing the Socially demo for angular2-meteor but I am not getting passed step 0: Bootstrapping.
The url to the tutorial is: https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping

My client/app.ts file contains this currently:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: '/client/app.html'
})
class Socially { }

bootstrap(Socially);
```

My app.html file:

```
Hello World!
```

and my index.html contains this:

```
<body>
    <app></app>
</body>
```

Once I run the code however, I receive this exception:

> EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on Socially

I run windows 10 pro and the project is created as a meteor --release 1.3.2.4 project.

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "djvanderburgt",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.3",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "0.5.5",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "^0.1.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "typings": "^1.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [angular2-meteor issue #301](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/301), the problem that you have mentioned should be fixed by updating `angular2-meteor` to 0.6.0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13004522)

Comment: This should be fixed in 0.6.0. Ref: https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/301

Comment: Then add this link and the information to the answer. Without this addition, the post is not a answer.